# How to compile related scss file using Live Sass Compiler?

Tags: css, sass, visual-studio-code, mustard-ui

I'm modifying a bunch of related scss files of [mustard-ui](https://mustard-ui.com/) css framework on vscode. The scss files are imported to `mustard-ui.scss` which is like this:

```
// Variables
@import 'vars/breakpoints';
@import 'vars/colors';


// Base
@import 'base/base';
```

I have also added this snipped to  [Live Sass Compiler](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-sass-compiler/blob/master/docs/settings.md) settings to define the path to put the output compiled .css files:

```
"liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [{
    "format": "expanded",
    "extensionName": ".css",
    "savePath": "/static/css/mystyle"
}]
```

The resulting compiled css then is obtained from `static/css/mystyle/mustard-ui.css`

The problem however is that when I edit one of the scss components, like `base.scss`, the `mutard-ud.scss` does not compile automatically to reflect changes. So I need to save it again with some dummy updates to get the updated `mustard-ui.css`. This is obviously tedious and absurd.

I'm wondering if there is a way to circumvent this? How to order the compiler to watch for related files?

Comment: There is an [open issue](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-sass-compiler/issues/83) about this.

Answer (score 5):

Do two thinks:

1. Every included file like base.scss must start with a underscore => _base.scss
2. edit your settings.json and add:

   > ```
   > "liveSassCompile.settings.includeItems": ["./path/to/your/main.scss"]
   > ```

If you now change _base.scss live sass compiler will compile main.scss! :)

Hope it help!

Comment: Tipp: To get the correct path, right click on the file in vsCode and copy relative path.